# Replacing images on mouseover with only childnodes and javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, child-nodes

I have to place three images side by side, and onmouseover function, when the user moves the mouse over an image , that particular image will be duplicate on the other two images. When the use moves the mouse out from the image, the image will restore as in initial page.
But I have to use childnodes for this. I'm not able to figure this out.

I've tried this following code, but it doesn't do anything.
I tried to paste the code here, but it was getting out onto the body of the message so I made this codepen where you can see it.
So far I'm only to get index[1] and index[2] pic to show up on index[0], but no other changes are happening. 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xNjezN

```
function heroes(q){
    if(q.src == imgArray[0])
    {
        for(var index=0; index<images.length; index++)
        {
            images[index] = document.getElementById("legends").childNodes[index];
            images[index].src = imgArray[0];
        }
    }
    else if(q.src == imgArray[1])
    {
        for(var index=0; index<images.length; index++)
        {
            images[index] = document.getElementById("legends").childNodes[index];
            images[index].src = imgArray[1];
        }
    }
    else if(q.src == imgArray[2])
    {
        for(var index=0; index<images.length; index++)
        {
            images[index] = document.getElementById("legends").childNodes[index];
            images[index].src = imgArray[2];
        }
    }
}
```

If someone can please suggest something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. There are two things to note. One, child nodes is actually a ["NodeList", which is only "array-like"](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodelist.asp). It can be converted to an array with Array.from(nodeList).
Second is the line break was being read as a "text" node, so actually showing 7 childNodes. You can filter them out with the [`Array.prototype.filter()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

[image: child nodes]

Then once you're working with the actual DOM elements, you can set and reset the src: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vwjwXm?editors=1010

Comment: Thank you so much. This one's perfect. Thank you for introducing me to array filter.

Answer (score 1):

If this is what you want, I've just selected all `img` tag that you want take src from on `onmouseout` event. `onmouseout` callback function I've just replaced the `mnImg.src` value to current image src.

If you want replace img src on mouse over you can replace `onmouseout` with `onmouseover`.

**On mouse out**

```js
let images = document.querySelectorAll('.img');
let mnImg = document.querySelector('#mnImg');

images.forEach(img => {
  img.onmouseout = function() {
    mnImg.src = this.src;
  };
})
```

```css
img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="legends">
    <img src="https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img921/9646/HCBvlG.jpg" id="mnImg">
    <img src="https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/3295/Fb6gMO.jpg" class='img'>
    <img src="https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img923/6089/01GQK7.jpg" class='img'>
  </div>
</body>
```

**On mouse over**

```js
let images = document.querySelectorAll('.img');
let mnImg = document.querySelector('#mnImg');

images.forEach(img => {
  img.onmouseover = function() {
    mnImg.src = this.src;
  };
})
```

```css
img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="legends">
    <img src="https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img921/9646/HCBvlG.jpg" id="mnImg">
    <img src="https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/3295/Fb6gMO.jpg" class='img'>
    <img src="https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img923/6089/01GQK7.jpg" class='img'>
  </div>
</body>
```